# server2012 domain name and exchange2013

Tags: exchange-2013

I have a server 2012 with a AD setup with domain.local setup.
I would like to add exchange to our new server 2012 just added.
our current setup:

1 server 2012 domain setup domain.local with AD
1 server 2012 (new) would like to add exchange on.
hosted emails(name.net), and website from godaddy (website name.net)

I would like to setup an exchange server to get away from godaddy emails.
but leave the website there for now.

Should i rename my domain.local to .net?

Any help from experts on what they would do would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Leave your Active Directory domain as .local (a rename can be challenging, and will require you to setup split DNS, its recommended to leave it as .local). Setup your MX records to point to your server, configure Exchange to be authoritative for the domains you own and want to configure mail for.

Also, installing Exchange on a domain controller (SBS excluded) is not a supported configuration, so it would be in your best interest to start up a new server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms.exch.setupreadiness.warninginstallexchangerolesondomaincontroller(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I did get a used system to keep exchange on it by itself. I will will look at this later today after my other project.